# How to compute the change in adjusted R-squared in R-?

Tags: r, model, compare

**In R-**, how can I get the **change in the adjusted R squared and the p-value attached to this change** (which would tell me whether this change is statistically significant) from one model to another ? In the case this is relevant, I am trying to compare **felm models** from the lfe package.

I tried a couple of functions, namely *lm.deltaR2(model1, model2)* and *modelCompare(model1, model2)* but this only gives me the change in *R squared* and not in the *adjusted R squared*. I thought about computing this change manually by subtracting the adjusted R squared from one model to another, which is an option, but then I don't have the statistical significance of this change.

What I would like to find would look something like this (Using fictive functions here)

`model.compare (felm1, felm2)`
`output : change in the adjusted R-squared = 0.02 ; p-value = 0.001`

Any suggestion? 
I guess two of my questions are:

- Is the statistical significance of the change in R squared **the same** than the statistical significance of the change in the adjusted R squared (would they show the same p-value?)
- Is there a way to **test** whether the two adjusted R squared values are significantly different from one another?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But these seem like they might be statistical questions which would be a better fit for [stats.se] in the first place.

Comment: not very familiar with the felm package.. and seems like anova doesn't work on it. you might have to write to the authors to ask about testing.. it's a somewhat different from linear model, isolated statistical method...